# Why is the 'hosts' field missing from this Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, stig

When running my script I keep getting "ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set". Can anyone please tell me what it is that I am missing. I am currently trying to implement DISA stig hardening on to 2 centos 6 virtual machines.

```
---
- name: Stig implementation
  hosts: Database
  tasks:


  - name: upgrade all packages
    command: yum upgrade -y

  - name: update all packages
    command: yum update -y

  - name: /etc/passd file is owned by root
    command: chown root:root /etc/passwd

  - name: remove rsh-server package
    command: yum erase rsh-server

  - name: bootload configuration owner is root
    command: chgrp root /etc/grub.conf

  - name: rshd service disabled
    command: chkconfig rsh off

  - name: rexecd service disabled
    command: chkconfig rexec off

  - name: remove telnet and telnet-server
    command: yum erase telnet-server && yum erase telnet

  - lineinfile: dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
               state=present
               regexp='PermitEmptyPasswords'
               line='PermitEmptyPasswords no'
               backup=yes

  - lineinfile: dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
               state=present
               regexp='HostbasedAuthentication'
               line='HostbasedAuthentication no'
               backup=yes

  - name: Change etc/group ownership
    command: chgrp root /etc/group

  - name: operating system must connect to external networks
    command:  chkconfig ip6tables on && service ip6tables start

  - name: add lines
    lineinfile: dest=/etc/audit/audit.rules
               line='{{item}}'
    with_items:
      - '-w /sbin/insmod -p x -k modules'
      - '-w /sbin/rmmod -p x -k modules'
      - '-w /sbin/modprobe -p x -k modules'
      - '-a always,exit -F arch=[b64] -S init_module -S delete_module -k modules'

  - name: disable xinetd
    command: chkconfig xinetd off && service xinetd stop

  - name: turn off and disable netconsole
    command: chkconfig netconsole off && service netconsole stop
```

A copy of my host file

```
[localhost]
x.x.x.x
[Database]
x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x
```

Comment: We'll need more details on the error-- what line does it occur on? Can you post the full output?

Comment: Also, as an aside, some commands you've listed already have ansible equivalents-- such as yum.

Comment: Check padding of tasks. Maybe one task accidentally became a play. And as stated in comments above many commands should be replaced with ansible native modules.

Comment: Are you passing the hosts file with `-i`? Also, as the others mentioned, `ansible-lint` would really help with some cleanup here.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a playbook... could you try removing the second line:

```
---
- hosts: Database
  tasks:
  ...
```